# Reusing Tomcat Tribes configuration to send messages between nodes

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have Tomcat session replication using static members tribe configuration in my server and it is working fine.  However, I wanted to leverage the same setup in my application to send messages between members of the cluster to facilitate my event architecture my app uses.  The reason I want to use this is for the following reasons:

1. Tribes is a peer to peer communication framework already built into tomcat.
2. Reuse the configuration of peers.
3. No need to add additional overhead of new libraries.

Is there a way to programmatically gain access to Tomcat's Cluster Channel object to send message over?  Or is there a way to figure out the members of the cluster to create your own channel to minimize the need to duplicate configuration?

Comment: I suppose you could make the argument that no matter what third-party message bus you went with, that it would come with some level of "lock-in", but it seems odd to tie some of your web application's functionality to a specific container, essentially rendering it non-portable.

Comment: Technically the Tribes portion is portable so if I had to move containers I could, but there will be some amount of code that would not be portable to your point.  Unless there is a way to get cluster members through a portable API (system properties, etc).  I just feel repeating that configuration of cluster members is important information I don't want to have in two places.

Comment: I have no experience with Tribes, but my best guess would be that you could somehow expose the Channel object (or whatever object you need) as an MBean and retrieve it via JNDI. Did a tiny bit of research, but I couldn't find anything obvious.

Comment: Something else to consider, if you are already using Spring in your application (a big if), and you are only relying on Tribes for session replication a more portable option might be to introduce Spring-Session with Redis. Then, once you bring Redis into the fold to support Spring-Session, you could use it as your message bus to support your eventing.

Comment: A similar thought had occurred to me, we're on grails which has spring under it so it's possible.  A very cheap solution would be to announce yourself by writing to the DB that you're here.  Then we can use tribes without digging around in tomcat and doing non-portable things.

Comment: We are currently using Spring-Session with Grails on my project. Check out this recently published plugin for more information: https://grails.org/plugin/spring-session

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using JMX to find the cluster configuration.  It's pretty hacky, but there might be an cleaner way to find this information in JMX.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/570194/Tomcat/find-Tomcat-cluster-members